# Let $t_n:=|s_n|$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and assume $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ has a supremum. Prove that $\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty $has an infimum.

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
$
\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty
$ be a sequence and set 
$
t_n:=|s_n|
$ for 
$n\in\mathbb{N}$. Assume that 
$\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ 
has a supremum. Prove that 
$\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ 
has an infimum.

Since I'm new to real analysis and proofs in general, I know my proof will be a bit  clumsy and but here is my attempt;
by definition of an absolute value,
$$t_n=\begin{cases} s_n &\text{if }s_n\geq0\\
                    -s_n &\text{if }s_n<0 \end{cases}$$
Let us consider the case where $s_n<0$. Then it follows that
$$\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\{-s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$$
$$\sup\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\sup\{-s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty\tag{*}$$
So the goal is to show that $\inf\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ exists. Since we know that $\{-s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is bounded by above from (*), then that MUST mean that if we take the negative of the sequence $\{-s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$, it will be bounded by below, as such:
$$-\sup\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=-\sup\{-s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$$
$$-\sup\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\inf\{s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$$
As for the case where $s_n\geq0$, I do not think it tells anything useful about the infimum, only about its supremum.

And here ends my proof. However, I can't shake the feeling that my proof is lacking or incomplete.

Is my proof correct? What am I missing? Is there another way to approach this question?

Comment: $|S_n| \leq M \iff -M \leq S_n \leq M$ hence $S_n$ has an infimum

Comment: Was it really just as simple? Thank you for the quick response!

Comment: Your equation $\sup\{t_n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\sup\{-s_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is wrong; for a counterexample, take $s_n=-1$ if $n$ is odd and $s_n=2$ if $n$ is even.

Comment: I see, thank you.